# Duda funcionamiento mkdir

Tags: php

En este código para subir una imagen ¿como funciona mkdir? Veo en [la documentación de php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php) que mkdir crea un directorio pero en el caso que muestro el directorio ya esta creado. Este ejemplo funciona perfectamente, tan solo quiero saber como funciona mkdir ¿crea la carpeta o solamente elige la carpeta especificada?

```
$id_banner=intval($_POST['id']);

$target_dir = "../../img/banner/";

$carpeta=$target_dir;

if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
    mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: mkdir creará la carpeta.

Comment: Mira el código. `mkdir` solo se ejecuta si no existe la carpeta(`if (!file_exists($carpeta))`), lo que ya te indica que lo que hace es crearla (_make dir_)

Comment: Ah, es cierto! Gracias

Comment: Sin esa comprobación PHP no sólo devuelve `false` sino que tira un error de tipo E_WARNING ojo con eso

Answer (score 1):

**mkdir** como bien ya sabes solo funciona para crear un directorio nuevo en la ruta que especifiques, ahora en el código que indicas evaluas si ya el directorio existe con al función **file_exists**, con esta función verifica si existe o no un archivo o directorio retornando como resultado un booleano (true/false ó 0/1), de ser falso mandas a crear el dirctorio asignandole el permido de **777**.

Answer (score 1):

mkdir (Make Directory) crea una carpeta y devuelve verdadero/falso dependiendo si la operación es exitosa. Según la [documentación PHP](https://php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php).

> bool mkdir ( string $directorio[, int $permisos= 0777 [, bool $recursivo=
>   false [, resource $contexto ]]] )

$directorio: Nombre de la carpeta

$permisos: Permisos de carpeta (no aplicable en sistemas windows)

$recursivo: Si tienes varias carpetas anidadas que no existen, crea una a una.

$contexto: Flujo de E/S.